# Cordova for Windows 10 WebSockets

Tags: windows-10-universal

I am using Cordova for Windows 10 with SignalR and I faced with a problem that only in Windows 10 SignalR transports except longPolling do not work.

Please help if you have such experience.
Thank you in advance.